# How do I make my own external command for a command-prompt?

Tags: python, command-prompt

I am making a coding language, I'm done making it now, but how do I make it like in a command prompt, and your file where you have your code inside, is called "code.scriptex", that you can type: `scriptex code.scriptex`?

What I mean with a command prompt:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLXLv.png)

I've searched it up, but nothing came up, so I came here on stackoverflow to ask it!

Code of language (It's just Python lmao):

```py
file = input()
pro = open(file,"r").read()
try:
    exec(pro)
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

I expect it to run my python file and make it work inside the command prompt.
I will edit my question if something isn't clear.

Comment: The interpreter you created needs to be able to handle input arguments. How you do this will depend on the language you implemented it in.

Comment: I editted it, I now added the code to.

Comment: Can you please describe a bit more precisely what exactly you want to do where? "like in a command prompt" is not very precise. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I've now added an image to it.

Comment: What operating system are you developing this on? You certainly can't use `exec()` to interpret your own language since it only understands python. But you can make your own `exec()` command.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Windows.

Comment: You first need to read about accepting command-line arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but i believe what you are trying to ask is, How to create a recognizable command in **Command Prompt (CMD)**.

For that you have to specify the directory which contains the files (`.exe` for the most part) which you want to make as command in the Environment Variable:-

1. Open My Computer, Right click and select `Properties`
   [image]
2. From there, select `Advanced System Settings` Option
   [image]
3. A Menu will pop up, from there select `Environment Variable` Option
   [image]
4. Another Menu will show up, there will be a section named `System Variables` in the new popup, it will contain a attribute named `path` in it, you have to edit that variable path by either `double clicking`it, or selecting path attribute and selecting `edit`option
   [image]
5. A Menu named `Edit Environment Variable` will show up, from there select the new option
   [image]
6. Upon selecting the new option, a input will start where you have to enter the directory of your script that you want to execute via comandline (i.e add the directory where your `scriptex.exe`/`scriptex.py` file exists)

[image: I am using "C:\Users\vasudeos\OneDrive\Desktop\hashcat-5.1.0" directory for example]

7. Now the select OK to finalize your changes

**WHAT WE DID:-**

We specified path to our specific directory, in Environment variable. Now we are able to access any file, inside that directory in an abstract way (without referencing its whole path).

**EXAMPLE:-**

[image]

This is the Directory which I added in the Environment variable path, now It allows me to access any file inside this folder, without specifying its full path. (You can see my CWD is different from the directory in which my `.exe` is, but still i am able to execute the file)